# React. How to set the placeholder until list of Components will be loaded fully?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, load

So I have the `Component` that renders the list of nested Components `Cri` and my goal is to make some placeholder display on the screen until the list of `Cri` Components will be fully loaded on the screen.

Any suggustions?

```
class Comp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isLoaded: true
    }
  }
  _func = () => {
    const lis = [];
    const { att, cri, media, res, st } = this.props;
    cri &&
      cri.map((row, i) => {
        var state = !row.available ? 'locked' : ''
        if (att.inProgress === false && att.itemId === row.cr && st) {
          var show = true
          state = result || state
        }
        lis.push(
          <Cri // my list of the Components Cri
            {...row}
            action={this._atte(row.cri, row.available)}
            key={i}
            mediaType={medpe}
            showOutcome={showe}
            state={state}
          />
        )
      })
    return lis
  }
  render() {
    const { isLoaded } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="main-container">
        <div className="sub-list">
          <div>
            {this._buildCrimesList()}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Use the syntax `{isLoaded ? <YourComponent /> : null}`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
render() {
  const { isLoaded } = this.state;

  if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading..</div>;

  return (
    <div className="main-container">
      <div className="sub-list">
        <div>
          {this._buildCrimesList()}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: And what it give me? The `{this._buildCrimesList()}` will not load resources anyway....

Comment: What? I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: We cannot use `setState` method inside `render()` - because React will crash and provide us with load state loop ( . It also sayed in the off React docs...

Comment: Yes.. I'm not using `setState` anywhere?

Comment: So and how we can change the state of `const { isLoaded } = this.state;` in case if the our function start to work just from `render()` method? This is my question, so how we can link the moment of function work end and the `isLoaded` status change inside `this.state`?

Comment: `const { isLoaded } = this.state;` does not change the state. I think you should read up on some React basics first, it might help you understand this code. I think what you're asking is to put `_buildCrimesList()` into `componentDidMount()`, but you haven't posted all your code so I don't know.